# Write at two locations in the console at the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, location

I need to write two things at the same time in the console. I have to display the partial results from when a recursive function comes back from recursion (i will have a wait time here) and in some other part of the screen I have to write the percentage of the stack that is full.

This must be done at the same time.
How do I do this in C#?

Edit: Also the progress must be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the position for writing using various properties in the [`Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) class, such as `CursorLeft` and `CursorTop`. You can't write to two positions at exactly the same time - just write to one location and then immediately write to another. That should be close enough.

Two options to avoid race conditions:

- Perform all the console writes in a single thread, e.g. using a producer/consumer queue of writes
- Use locking - just have a method which does the complete "set position and write" operation within a lock.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

If your main thread is waiting, busy with your recursive function, the only option is to use another thread to show the percentage of stack.